# How do I make a field optional inside a terraform resource?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create VMs for both cluster and single node deployments.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "app" {
    name   = "${var.name_prefix}-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
    location = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name}"
    availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.avset.id}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.networkinterface-app.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
    vm_size = "${var.vm_size}"
    count = "${var.app_nodes}"
```

The setup works well for the cluster node deployments with `availability_set_id` configured but fails as in single node I don't have a need to configure `availability_set_id`.

I am using `Terraform v0.11.2` and `* provider.azurerm: version = "~> 1.0"` as versions of terraform and azurerm provider currently.

Can anyone help me how to use a conditional in this case to handle both scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to wrap it in a module and then have two resources and  use `count = "${var.somecond ? 1 : 0}"` do determine which one is active.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be the only way to accomplish the stated goal at this time 0.11.3

Answer (score 1):

Although @matti solution may work in some cases, there are many that it won't work.

For instance, `aws_api_gateway_api_key` has an optional param `value`, that specifies a value for the API Key. If ommited, AWS itself is going to generate a key. However, one can't simply pass empty string or number to it, as it will raise an error:

`Error: module.some_api_key.aws_api_gateway_api_key.api_key: expected length of value to be in the range (30 - 128), got`

Unfortunately, there's no way to set a value to an undefined value currently (0.11.8) on Terraform. An [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5471) has been raised on github in 2016.

Furtunately, Terraform 0.12 is going to have an `null` value, that unsets the variable, as seen in this [preview post](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements#conditionally-omitted-argumentshttps://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements#conditionally-omitted-arguments). Terraform 0.12 is expected to be released later this summer.